# Как определить что у записи наибольший id

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю выборку из базы данных и вывожу записи

```
$naprPod = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `poDdirections` WHERE `iDdirections` = '1' ORDER BY `id` ASC");
while ($dIDpoD = mysql_fetch_assoc($naprPod))
{
//вывод записи
}
```

как определить запись у которой наибольший **id** ? 
Хочу эту запись в отдельный блок выделить

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем случае это будет последняя запись в списке.

```
$naprPod = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `poDdirections` WHERE `iDdirections` = '1' ORDER BY `id` ASC");
$last = null;
while ($dIDpoD = mysql_fetch_assoc($naprPod)) {
   //вывод каждой записи
   $last = $dIDpoD;
}
if (!empty($last)) {
   //вывод последней записи
}
```

Если не нужно ничего кроме этой записи, тогда

```
"SELECT * FROM `poDdirections` WHERE `iDdirections` = '1' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: У вас случаем не выведется в конце две одинаковых записи? Один раз в цикле и один в условии?

Comment: Задачи такого отбора не стояло, но это очень легко сделать в данном примере. Достаточно просто выводить $last ДО того, как она будет переопределена присвоением $dIDpoD.